# How were they flying in Chronicle

Tags: chronicle

I know that they had telekinesis, but what were they moving? Were they moving themselves or some other way?

Answer (score 3):

They were moving themselves.  Apparently their telekinesis is [reactionless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionless_drive), which allows them to push heavy objects without having their bodies feel the equal and opposite reaction.  This also allows counter-intuitive things like them moving their own bodies with the telekinesis.  When they fly, this is what they're doing, using the telekinesis to lift themselves.